# Issue with PDF.JS in the latest version of aura components

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, pdf

I'm making use of [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library to parse a pdf into images. I'm importing the library by making use of static resources and this library/below logic is working fine if the custom component API Version is **<= 39**. If I try to increase the custom component api version above **39** I'm getting an error **'Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'document' of undefined]'**

**Error with this line:** var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});

Sample Code

```
**HTML**
<ltng:require scripts='/resource/POC_PDF_JS ,
                      /resource/POC_PDF_WORKER_JS' afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadpdf}"/> 

**JS Logic**
var pdfData = atob(pdfbase64data);
console.log('PDFJS ', pdfjsLib);    // this is getting printed as object which contains getDocument()
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = $A.get('$Resource.POC_PDF_WORKER_JS');
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
console.log('loadingTask ', loadingTask); 

loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    console.log('Debugger pdf ',pdf);
}, function(error) {
     alert(error);
});
```

I tried changing to different versions of library but I see same issue. Is there anything that i'm missing or is there any alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Workers are not supported in Aura, and as a consequence, anything that tries to run a worker in Aura will inevitably fail. This limitation is on purpose, as workers would be able to circumvent Locker Service API security restrictions, and are therefore not allowed. You'll need to have it do its work without the benefit of a worker.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding

```
globalThis = window;
```

before setting

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc
```